# LINQ Select skips row if navigation property is null

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Frameowrk 7, and have the following LINQ query to select data into a data transfer object (DTO). To select data from navigation properties I use `Include` to enable eager loading of the specified properties. The table currently has two rows, but only one of them are returned in response to the following query:

```
var jobs = context.CorepJobs
            .Include(j => j.CompanyNavigation)
            .Include(j => j.WellNavigation.FieldNavigation)
            .Select(j =>
                new CorepJobDTO()
                {
                    Id = j.Id,
                    Created = j.Created,
                    DepthAsFeet = j.DepthAsFeet,
                    JobType = j.JobType,
                    State = j.State,
                    ProjectNo = j.ProjectNo,
                    CompanyName = j.CompanyNavigation.CompanyName,
                    WellName = j.WellNavigation.Name,
                    FieldName = j.WellNavigation.FieldNavigation.Name
                }
            ).AsEnumerable();
```

If some properties are `null`, I would expect the query to populate the corresponding properties of the DTO with `null`. Instead what happens, is that if the `FieldNavigation` property is `null`, the whole row is skipped and only one of the two rows are returned. If I leave out the last property (`FieldName`) in the `Select` block, both rows are returned.

I have also tried

```
FieldName = j.WellNavigation.FieldNavigation != null =? j.WellNavigation.FieldNavigation.Name : ""
```

without any luck.

Any ideas to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3186

Comment: Nice find! That has to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check type of 'FieldName' property, whether it accepts null or not. Then try

FieldName = j.WellNavigation.FieldNavigation != null ? j.WellNavigation.FieldNavigation.Name : null

Comment: `FieldName` is just a string, so it is nullable.